# Odoo custom filter domain field on load view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I'm making a module for reservations in Odoo 9 and one field of my model is populated based if it's reserved or no. Basically my model is:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    ....
    room_id = fields.Many2one('reservation.room', string="Room")
```

I've defined an `onchange` function that return a domain to filter the room_ids that aren't reserved:

```
@api.onchange('date')
def _set_available_room(self):
    .....
    return {'domain': {'room_id': [('id', 'in', res)]}}
```

This works fine and when I set the date, the rooms are filtered ok. My problem is when I save a reservation and enter again to edit it. The `room_id` field show all values and only when I change the `date` the `room_id` is filtered.

I've tried using the `domain` attribute in the field definition like this, but it doesn't works:

```
room_id = fields.Many2one('reservation.room', string="Room", domain=lambda self: self._get_available_slots())
```

How can I filter this field on the load view using my function than search for available rooms?

Comment: How is the `res` variable computed?

Comment: By a SQL query `self.env.cr.execute('SELECT id FROM reservation_room......')` and then `res=self.env.cr.fetchall()`. As I said, it works fine on the onchange event

Comment: Why not try with overriding `name_search` method

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've override the `name_search` method and it works fine. In the field view I have set the `context` to pass the date and in the `domain` I have filtered by a fake field like this: `domain="[('is_available','=',True)]"`. Then in the `name_search` method, if it's filtered by `is_available` I execute all the SQL to get the available rooms.

Comment: @CarlosMayo thanks for the answer. Good luck in development ;)